# popBackStack() not working on PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, preferencefragment

I have a `AppCompatActivity` with different `PreferenceFragments`. I am adding `fragments` to `backstack` using `addToBackStack()` call but while retrieving fragments using `popBackStack()`, the `activity` does not show `fragment`(`UI` not updated) however `getBackStackEntryCount()` decreases with `popBackStack()` call. What could be the reason?

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame_settings, new SettingsPreferenceFragment1())
            .addToBackStack("SettingsPreferenceFragment1")
            .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if ( getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public static class SettingsPreferenceFragment1 extends PreferenceFragment {
        ...
        ...
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_settings1);
            ...
            ...
        }

        @Override
            OnClick(View view){
                if(view == btnNext){
                    getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame_settings, new SettingsPreferenceFragment2())
                        .addToBackStack("SettingsPreferenceFragment2")
                        .commit();
                }
            }
    }

    public static class SettingsPreferenceFragment2 extends PreferenceFragment {
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_settings2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need to add first fragment in the activity to back stack. Any fragments replacing the first one needs to go to back stack.
Also, where are you setting/overriding `onClick()`? shouldn't that be in the settings activity?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Support Fragment, if so then you need to use `getSupportFragmentManager` instead of `getFragmentManager`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but getSupportFragmentManager() does not support PreferenceFragment.